# SQL Server taking several minutes to list tables from a database that has three tables and no records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am working through Adam Freeman's book "Pro ASP.Net Core 3".  I have just dropped and recreated my database using the latest version of Sql Server Management Studio 2019 (just installed yesterday), hoping that my problem would be resolved.  It hasn't.  At this point, the database has three small tables and no records in any of them.  Yet, when I try to expand the Tables node, it takes several minutes.  A customer of my company uses SSMS 2014 to manage a database with around 100 tables, a few of which have several million records each.  The tables node expands instantly.  What could be causing this delay for me?

Comment: Does the CPU actiivty spike?

Comment: No.  Task Manager shows SSMS using 0% of the processor

Comment: Is it a database running on your local machine, or a remote database in the cloud? CenturyLink caused major internet outages last weekend and there are still problems at other ISPs recovering from that. You could run up a copy of PingPlotter to monitor connectivity between your workstation and a remote database to watch for packet loss and wild variations in latency.

Comment: It's a local database on my machine